# discord.py BS4 get copy to clipboard info from html

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, discord.py

I have the following html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-raised btn-success" id="button-copy-number" onclick='copyToClipboard("123456")' type="button">Copy number to clipboard</button>
```

How can i get the number from the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to extract the number from `onclick=` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''<button class="btn btn-raised btn-success" id="button-copy-number" onclick='copyToClipboard("123456")' type="button">Copy number to clipboard</button>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

# 1. locate the button
btn = soup.select_one('#button-copy-number')

# 2. get the onclick= attribute
txt = btn['onclick']

# 3. get the number
n = int(txt.split('"')[-2])

print(n)
```

Prints:

```
123456
```

---

Or: using `re` module:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''<button class="btn btn-raised btn-success" id="button-copy-number" onclick='copyToClipboard("123456")' type="button">Copy number to clipboard</button>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

btn = soup.select_one('#button-copy-number')
txt = btn['onclick']

n = int(re.search(r'(\d+)', txt).group(1))
print(n)
```